# Detect mobile zoom & default mobile resolution

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, mobile

I am working on mobile compatibility of a site for my third party product, and I am facing position fixed issue.I am fixing a footer to viewport's bottom.
Android below 2.3 & iOS devices below 5 do not support position fixed.
For such devices currently I have fix that I am calculation current width of viewport and then  apply width to footer by js.
But problem occurs when there is less content on site or client's site add auto zoom meta in head.In this case screen is zoomed and content inside of footer breaks.
I can't use iScroll because it locks zoom functionality , and I can't mess with client's page.
Please suggest me some logical solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrote custom function , which people used to use in ancient times (IE6 times).
It checks if browser supports position fixed or not.If not then adjusts its position according to scroll/zoom.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

so the zooming does not occur at the page load - but it's still available to the user!

Comment: I am building third party product , so can't mess with client's site.